# sum a numeric column subject to a group-by inside a group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql

Difficult to express .. so an example :

A table which records number of items sold by vendors, and the date of sale :

```
   item    |  vendor  |  count  |  date
   item1   |   john   |    1    | 2021-01-15
   item4   |   john   |    2    | 2021-01-15
   item1   |   paul   |    1    | 2021-01-15
   item4   |  robert  |    1    | 2021-01-16
   item1   |   john   |    7    | 2021-01-16
   item3   |  claire  |    4    | 2021-01-17
   etc ...
```

Yes, John is a good vendor :)

Considering only this extract to make it more simple, I would like to obtain this result (so for a choosen period of time) :

```
   item   |  total  |  per_user
   item1  |    9    | john:8,paul:1
   item3  |    4    | claire:4
   item4  |    3    | john:2,robert:1
```

With :

```
  select item, sum(count) as total, group_concat(distinct concat(vendor,':',count)) as per_user
  where date etc..
  group by item
```

I get this instead :

```
  item1 |  9  | john:1,paul:1,john:7 
  etc ...
```

So how to aggregate vendors in the same group_concat() ?

Comment: This is a code smell.  Why does your application want to retrieve data aggregated in this way?  Isn't it just going to parse the `per_user` resultset column in order to disaggregate it as soon as it's received?  If so, just fetch the disaggregated results, e.g. `select item, vendor, sum(count) from table group by item, vendor`.  If you want the database to also return the total for each item, just append `with rollup` to the `group by` clause.

Comment: On SO, I always try to use a very more simple example than mine to be sure people will get quickly my request, avoiding my own shema where I would have to explain each column and thei content. TIME is a scarce commodity, and I am very grateful for the answers ! For information, this column will appear in a web datatable, and I want it to appear like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two levels of aggregation:

```
select item,
       group_concat( vendor, ':', cnt  order by cnt desc separator ',') as vendors
from (select item, vendor, sum(count) as cnt
      from example
      group by item, vendor
     ) iv
group by item;
```

Comment: Thanks, thinking of "add a level" in sql is always useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to aggregate twice.

```
SELECT x.item,
       sum(x.count) total,
       group_concat(x.vendor, ':', x.count) per_user
       FROM (SELECT t.item,
                    t.vendor,
                    sum(t.count) count
                    FROM elbat t
                    GROUP BY t.item,
                             t.vendor) x
       GROUP BY x.item;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution for you. Though, I don't know your **MySql** version. But, I write a code for you in MySQL v8. I have use `CTE` AND window function to achieve your answer. Please check the code and link of Code: => [**db-fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uEftHRxEfxFvg9t7jsLXcs/0).

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (item Varchar(20),vendor Varchar(20),DataCOUNT INT,MyDate Date);

INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES('item1','john',1,'2021-01-15');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES('item4','john',2,'2021-01-15');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES('item1','paul',1,'2021-01-15');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES('item4','robert',1,'2021-01-16');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES('item1','john',7,'2021-01-16');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES('item3','claire',4,'2021-01-17');

WITH CTE AS
(SELECT  item,vendor,
       SUM(DataCOUNT) OVER(PARTITION BY item) AS TotalCount,
       CAST(SUM(DataCOUNT) OVER(PARTITION BY item,vendor) AS CHAR(50)) AS SubCount

FROM MYTABLE)
,MyY AS 
(SELECT DISTINCT item,TotalCount,
       CONCAT(vendor, ':', SubCount) SubCountWithUser
FROM CTE)
SELECT item,MAX(TotalCount) AS total  ,
       GROUP_CONCAT(SubCountWithUser) AS per_user
FROM MyY GROUP BY item
```